# GitLab Weblogic CI setup

Tags: gitlab, weblogic-10.x, gitlab-ci-runner

Do you know if it possible to do CI Pipeline with Weblogic 10.3.4.0 deployment and Java 8 Spring Project?

If yes, do you have any tips for me?

I successfully deployed Project on CI Gitlab and configured yml file but I didn't find much info on net about weblogic integration with GitLab, thanks for help in advance!

Kind Regards !